# XSD Validation :How to get current Node name when exception occur

Tags: xml, scala, xsd, xsd-validation

I am doing xsd validation, and trying to get the current node name when exception occur, but I'm getting a `null`

I have tried the code below -

```
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource
import javax.xml.validation.SchemaFactory
import org.xml.sax.SAXException
import scala.xml.Elem

object Validator {
 def main(args: Array[String]) {
  val result =
    if (validate("students.xml", "students.xsd"))
      "Valid!"
    else
      "Not valid."
  println(result)
}

def validate(xmlFile: String, xsdFile: String): Boolean = {
  val schemaLang = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  val factory = SchemaFactory.newInstance(schemaLang)
  val schema = factory.newSchema(new StreamSource(xsdFile))
  val validator = schema.newValidator()
  try {
    validator.validate(new StreamSource(xmlFile))
  } catch {
    case ex: SAXException => println(ex.getMessage)
      val msg:Elem= validator.getProperty("http://apache.org/xml/properties/dom/current-element-node").asInstanceOf[Elem]
      println("Current Node - "+msg)
      return false

    case ex: Exception => println(ex.getStackTrace)
  }
  true
 }
}
```

output:

```
cvc-datatype-valid.1.2.1: 'Dinkar' is not a valid value for 'integer'.
Current Node - null
Not valid.
```

Please do help me on this to get it done. Thanks!

Comment: Seems the validator might give back a SAXParseException if you configured an ErrorHandle, which might give you access to line number, column, system ID or public ID.

Answer (score 0):

This is an interesting idea, but it isn't possible to get the `scala.xml.Elem` from the `javax.xml.validation.Validator` when validation fails, since `javax` doesn't know anything about `scala.xml`.  It would be nice if it could just be summoned with `asInstanceOf[Elem]`, but it would need to a class of type `Elem` to be changed at runtime.